# Unity WebGL Build on BrightSign Player stuck loading

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, media-player, unity-webgl

I want to run a *Unity WebGL* build on a [BrightSign XT1144](https://www.brightsign.biz/digital-signage-products/XT-product-line/XT1144) player. (What should be possible in theory...)
Therefore I created an absolute simplistic Unity project (using v2020.2.6f1), not much more than displaying an image, and build it for WebGL. Then I published this build to the player using *BrightAuthor:connected* (using a HTML 5 Widget).

When I start the player the typical Unity WebGL loading screen appears and stops at approx. 90%.

Right now the build works fine on a local server and also online, but not on the BrightSign player.

I played around with the build/player settings in Unity but the behaviour of the build didn't change. (And of course I googled my fingertips bloody, but it's hard to find any kind of valid information...)

Does anyone already have experience with a scenario like this? Any help would be appreciated! :)

**Things I tried:**

- Enabled Development Build
- Disabled Compression
- Disabled Data Caching
- Disabled Engine Code Stripping
- Updated BrightSign OS to 8.2.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working!
[This post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1798970/unity-20202-webgl-both-async-and-sync-fetching-of.html)  in the Unity forum got me on the right track.
With the following publishing settings, my Unity (2020.3.2) WebGL build runs on the *BrightSign XT1144* player. (BrightSignOS 8.x)[image: Unity WebGL publishing settings]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles across this, got close with asj's solution but, at least when building with Unity 2021.3.1f1 and running on a Brightsign XD1033 on OS 8.4.14, I was getting the error

> It seems your browser does not support running Unity WebGL content from file:// urls. Please upload it to an http server, or try a different browser.

Looks like Unity WebGL projects won't run locally anymore. Followed Brightsign's instructions [here](https://github.com/brightsign/node.js-starter-project) to get started with a NodeJS server on the Brightsign to host the WebGL. Moved everything created by the Unity build (index.html, Build, TemplateData, StreamingAssets) to a `client` folder within the `node.js-starter-project-master` folder. Modified the `index.js` express script to

```
const path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/storage/sd')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./client')));


app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/index.html'));
});
app.listen(9090, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9090!');
});
```

Also had to update `webpack.config.js` so the `client` directory was copied to `dist`. Replaced the `CopyWebpackPlugin` section with

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: './client',
        to: 'client'
      }]
    })
```

From here, followed the instructions on the Brightsign GitHub to setup the NodeJS presentation. Added an HTML5 widget to the presentation with the Site Source URL at `http://localhost:9090`.

Under `Presentation Settings>Support Content>Files` I added the `node-server.zip` file created by webpack.

And it's still not doing what I need. Looks like it's technically working but the XD1033 isn't capable of playing my content (a relatively simple 2D game) smoothly. It will show the Unity player but has a hard time loading the game assets. But, if I access the url from a laptop connected to the Brightsign it loads just fine. A simpler game or a more powerful Brightsign might work better.

I might be able to get it working better with some optimization and tweaking but at the moment it's not worth my time and effort. I can just build for Windows and use a PC. Was just trying to use a Brightsign since we've found them easier to maintain long term. Might come back to it if I get bored and will update if I get it working better.